# Put things in disorder?

Tags: idiomatic-language

Is it ok to say

> Put things in disorder

meaning making a mess of things?

Or does it sound weird?

I'm asking because apparently the phrase 'put things in order' exists and is totally fine.

How about the opposite?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is a little odd. The word "put" suggests a methodical approach of deliberately placing things in a certain way. But disorder suggests a lack of such a method.

I'd prefer

> disorder things.

or more naturally, your expression:

> make a mess (of things).

In specific contexts (such as a method to randomly disorder a list) you can use "shuffle" or "randomize".

Comment: Another word that comes to mind is "scramble".

Comment: "Throw" is a good verb to replace "put" here. I've certainly heard people refer to things being thrown into disorder before.

Comment: @FredLarson thank you! Can I say, 'I don't like when people scramble my things'?

Comment: @AdmiralJota thank you!

Comment: It would work as a deliberate play on words, kind of like a "ruly crowd" or "kempt hair".  But yeah, it would not be common usage by any means.